# SVG line stays in screen after leaving mouse

Tags: css, svg, transition

I've made a div, with 4 svg lines in it.
When hovering the div, the x- and y-axis changes using transition and transform.

Everything works fine, got it working but when i leave the mouse from the hover field, the svg line stays just a couple pixels in screen.

[image]

Check the example at the bottom of the page..

Any explanations/solutions will be very appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="blok">
    <svg width="200" height="100">
        <line class="left" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="-100"/>
        <line class="bottom" x1="-200" y1="100" x2="0" y2="100"/>
        <line class="right" x1="200" y1="100" x2="200" y2="200"/>
        <line class="top" x1="200" y1="0" x2="400" y2="0"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.blok{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ddd;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

svg line {
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke: #000;
    fill: none;

}
svg line.top, line.bottom {
    stroke-dasharray: 200;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
    transition: transform .2s ease-out;
}

svg line.left, line.right {
    stroke-dasharray: 100;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-out;
    transition: transform .1s ease-out;
}

svg line.top{
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
svg line.right{
    -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
    transition-delay: .2s;
}
svg line.bottom{
    -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
    transition-delay: .3s;
}
svg line.left{
    -webkit-transition-delay: .5s;
    transition-delay: .5s;
}

.blok:hover svg line.left {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
    transform: translateY(100px);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.blok:hover svg line.bottom {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
    transform: translateX(200px);
    -webkit-transition-delay: .1s;
    transition-delay: .1s;
}
.blok:hover svg line.right {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    -webkit-transition-delay: .3s;
    transition-delay: .3s;
}
.blok:hover svg line.top {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-200px);
    transform: translateX(-200px);
    -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
    transition-delay: .4s;
}
```

[**JsFiddle HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrqzg1fm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting the lines from outside the svg

```
<div class="blok">
    <svg width="200" height="100">
        <line class="left" x1="0" y1="-5" x2="0" y2="-100"/>
        <line class="bottom" x1="-205" y1="100" x2="0" y2="100"/>
        <line class="right" x1="200" y1="105" x2="200" y2="205"/>
        <line class="top" x1="205" y1="0" x2="400" y2="0"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shedali/vr8xj27n/

Comment: You're my hero, nice solution! Still wondering what might cause this 'bug'.. Who knows someone can still explain that to me :)

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify the whole thing and have a single line around the rectangle and transition the `stroke-dashoffset` rather than moving four individual lines.

SVG

```
<svg width="200" height="100">
    <polyline class="line" points="0,0, 0,100, 200,100, 200,0 0,0"/>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
svg .line {
    stroke-width: 10;
    stroke: #000;
    fill: none;
    stroke-dasharray: 600;
    stroke-dashoffset: 600;
}
svg .line {
    stroke-dashoffset: 600;
    -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease-out;
}

.blok:hover svg .line {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/vrqzg1fm/2/)

Comment: this is a more elegant solution